# Fragment - ViewPager Common Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Let's say I have a common toolbar or searchbutton on top of my (4) fragments in a ViewPager. (Each fragment in the ViewPager has the same button) and EditText view. If the search button is defined with id: `@+id/searchButton`, (or anything else) then when I call:
`(Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton)` in Fragment 2, it's relatively random which search button of the 4 is returned (not necessarily the one in Fragment 2).  How can I ensure the one in Fragment 2 is the one that is referred to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was using `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchButton);`.  In reality, I should have been using `getView().findViewById(R.id.searchButton);`.